# Is this density operator unphysical?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, density-operator

I have been told that this form of density function:
$$\rho(q)=\sum_{\mathbf p} M(\mathbf p ,\mathbf q)h^\dagger_\mathbf ph_{\mathbf p - \mathbf q} $$
where $h^\dagger(h)$ is the holon creation(destruction) operator and $M(\mathbf p ,\mathbf q)$ is the spin-polaron coupling function defined in this paper [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.44.317), would be unphysical. Can anyone enlighten me why? Thank you in advance. 
  
-edit-
The paper basically describes the motion of a hole in a 2-D Heisenberg antiferromagnet in a representation where holes are described as spinless fermions called holons and spins are treated as normal bosons. Here, they derived the spin-polaron t-J Hamiltonian using linear spin wave theory. A Bogoliubov transformation 
$$\alpha_q=u_qa_q-v_qa_q^\dagger $$
where $a_q(a_q^\dagger)$ is the spin destryction(creation) operators to arrive at
$$H_t=\frac{zt}{N}\sum_{\mathbf p,\mathbf q}M(\mathbf p,\mathbf q)h^\dagger_\mathbf ph_{\mathbf p-\mathbf q}\alpha_\mathbf q+H.c.$$
where z is the coordination number, t is the transfer integral constant and N is some normalization factor and $M(\mathbf p,\mathbf q)=(u_\mathbf q\gamma_{\mathbf p - \mathbf q}+v_\mathbf q\gamma_\mathbf p)$. Correspondingly: $$u_q=\left(\frac{1+\nu_q}{2\nu_q}\right)^{1/2}$$$$v_q=-sgn(\gamma_q)\left(\frac{1-\nu_q}{2\nu_q}\right)^{1/2}$$ and
$$\nu_q=\sqrt{1-\alpha\gamma_q}$$
$$\gamma_q=\frac{1}{2}(\cos q_x+\cos q_y)$$, defining the lattice constant $\alpha=1$. By the way, I was the one defining that density operator and it is taken from any articles.

Comment: Please make your post self-contained (=add the relevant info from the paper here).

Comment: yes if you could provide details since you link to a paper behind a paywall.

Comment: Thank you for these comments.. I'll edit the question right away to give more information.